# Filestack Api Inrtegration in php

Tags: php, filestack

I am using filestack api in php. I am trying to make connection with api. I just included its client library file and i am getting an error. Please give me suggestion that which file i have to include for to make connection with Filestack Api. I am including right file? I had downloaded library from github ( https://github.com/filestack/filestack-php/ ). Below the code:

```
include 'ext-lib/filestack/filestack/FilestackClient.php';
use Filestack\FilestackClient;
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Trait 'Filestack\Mixins\CommonMixin' 
>   not found in C:*****************\filestack\FilestackClient.php 
>   on line 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQVad.png)

Comment: This may mean that the path to the file does not match the PSR-4 convention, while still being in the folder (meaning that the classmap generator finds the class when building the optimized autoloader, even if it does not actually respect psr-4).
Can you paste the path to the file in which the trait is defined ?

Comment: There may be a typo mistake

Comment: 'filestack/mixins/CommonMixin.php' in this file trait CommonMixin is definded.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you should use composer to install this package to your project, as it'll download all the needed dependencies.

Technically, you can manually include the Filestack library using the [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) function like so:

```
<?php
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'ext-lib\' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');

use Filestack\FilestackClient;
$client = new FilestackClient($test_api_key);
```

But, even though this will resolve all your Filestack paths, it'll still not work because  the Filestack SDK has a dependency on GuzzleHttp, so you'll have to manually install that as well.  Unfortunately, there is no easy way to manually install GuzzleHttp.

===========

If you really can't use composer, I've created an example project with all the vendor dependencies downloaded.  Just make sure you include the vendor/autoload.php file wherever you need to call Filestack objects.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7iwritw0pcstwjb/filestack-phptest.zip